# How do I remove a click event from a custom control using reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, reflection

I have a custom control (MenuButton) in WPF that subscribes to a Click event. I now want to use reflection to unsubscribe from the event. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
private void RemoveClickEvent(MenuButton mbButton)
{
    FieldInfo fiFieldInfo = mbButton.GetType().GetField("Click", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                        BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField);
    object objValue = fiFieldInfo.GetValue(mbButton);
    PropertyInfo piProprtyInfo = mbButton.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

    EventHandlerList ehEventHandlers = (EventHandlerList)piProprtyInfo.GetValue(mbButton, null);
    ehEventHandlers.RemoveHandler(objValue, ehEventHandlers[objValue]);
}
```

I can successfully get the FieldInfo object, but the PropertyInfo object comes out as null. How do I fix my code so that the method works properly? For the record, I am targeting .NET Framework 4.

Edit:

Here is how I subscribe to the events.

```
private void PageStart()
{
    //Subscribe to the necessary event when a page is first loaded
    foreach (MenuButton mbItem in mbMenuButtonsList)
    {
        if (mbItem.HideExtraInfo == true)
        {
            mbButton.Click += (sender, e) => ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, true);
        }
        else
        {
            mbButton.Click += (sender, e) => ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, false);
        }
    }
}

private void PageEnd()
{
    //When moving to the next page, unsubscribe from the events
    foreach (MenuButton mbItem in mbMenuButtonsList)
    {
        RemoveClickEvent(mbItem);
    }
}
```

Edit #2:

Something I neglected to mention, some of the events I use in my project also require the MenuButton to be passed in, like so:

```
UIElementCollection ctrlControls = MainCanvas.Children;
mbButton.Click += (sender, e) => ChangeControls(sender, e, mbButton, ctrlControls, false);
```

How do I work around this if I stop using Lambda expressions?

Comment: Events in WPF are `RoutedEvent`, I am not sure you can simply use reflection to modify the handler lists.

Comment: @TanveerBadar If what I'm attempting is not possible in WPF, can you suggest another method?

Comment: How is the event subscribed to? Can you show that code? It will be much easier to unsubscribe once we know how events are being hooked-up.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Question has been updated to show this.

Comment: `sender` is the MenuButton itself.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using lambdas to subscribe to your events, you use methods, unsubscribing is easy:

```
if (mbItem.HideExtraInfo == true)
{
    mbButton.Click += ShowControls;
}
else
{
    mbButton.Click += HideControls;
}

private void ShowControls(object sender, EventArgs e) => ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, true);
private void HideControls(object sender, EventArgs e) => ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, false);

private void PageEnd()
{
    //When moving to the next page, unsubscribe from the events
    foreach (MenuButton mbItem in mbMenuButtonsList)
    {
        mbItem.Click -= ShowControls;
        mbItem.Click -= HideControls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any consequences to unsubscribing to the Click event when that method isn't assigned to it? i.e. If Click only subscribes to ShowControls, there's no issue with attempting to unsubscribe from both it AND HideControls?

Comment: No, you can always safely unsubscribe - even if you did not subscribe first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there's another issue I've got. I've updated the question to add some info I previously neglected to mention.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to handle, don't use lambda expressions!

```
private void PageStart()
{
    //Subscribe to the necessary event when a page is first loaded
    foreach (MenuButton mbItem in mbMenuButtonsList)
    {
        if (mbItem.HideExtraInfo == true)
        {
            mbButton.Click += true_handler;
        }
        else
        {
            mbButton.Click += false_handler;
        }
    }
}

void true_handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, true);
}

void false_handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ShowOrHideControls(sender, e, false);
}

private void PageEnd()
{
    //When moving to the next page, unsubscribe from the events
    foreach (MenuButton mbItem in mbMenuButtonsList)
    {
        if (mbItem.HideExtraInfo == true)
        {
            mbButton.Click -= true_handler;
        }
        else
        {
            mbButton.Click -= false_handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there's another issue I've got. I've updated the question to add some info I previously neglected to mention.

Comment: `sender` is the MenuButton. Type cast it to proper type in `ShowOrHideControls`.